# Tls 1.2 with .net 3.5 framework issue

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, tls1.2

We are using .net 3.5 framework and we want to use tls1.2.
As I know that tls1.2 is not supported with .net3.5
so for that we have used

```
const System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols tls12 = (System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols)0x00000C00;
const SecurityProtocolType tls12Type = (SecurityProtocolType)tls12;             
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = tls12Type;
```

and it worked on windows 8 and 10 but not working with windows 7.Does anyone have an idea why it is not working?

Comment: And have you actually [enabled TLS1.2 on Windows 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client) ?

Comment: You need at least .Net Framework 4.5.2 installed in the machine.